# Cannot change variable outside error scope

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change a variable once it's entered the error scope, my problem is that it changes within the scope but code immediately after the block stays the same.

I'm basically looping though images to see if they exist on a remote server, if they don't replace the image with a placeholder.

I'm not sure if this is error scope specific?

```
var featuredItems = [];
            var normalItems = [];

            //Change the image so we source all images for the same size.
            $.each(items, function(){
                var lastDot = this['image'].lastIndexOf('.');
                var item = this;
                item['image'] = item['image'].substring(0, lastDot - 1) + '19.jpg';

                $("<img>", 
                {
                    src: item['image'],
                    error: function() 
                    {  
                        //Error scope.
                        console.log(item['image'] + " does not exist.");

                        //This will not change.
                        item['image'] = "img/placeholder.png";
                    }
                });



                if(item['featured'])
                {
                    featuredItems.push(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    normalItems.push(item);
                }
            });

            items = featuredItems.concat(normalItems);
```

Comment: what is an error scope? point out clearly what you're meaning to say..

Comment: It's the error block, anything winthin it is within the error scope.

Comment: What's the question? is `testbool` what you are trying to change?

Comment: I added some additional information.

Comment: Changing `item['image']` won't change the `src` of the `<img>` element. You need to do `this.src = 'placeholderURL'`.

Comment: That's just an array item thats used later on. My problem is any variable leaving the error scope reverts.

Comment: Don't forget that the `error` scope occurs asynchronously. It's just like AJAX -- you can't refer to the values it set in the code right after it.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks, that's what is causing the issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out error block is asynchronous thanks Barmar.

I used this piece of code instead works nicely BUT beware that if the file you reference doesn't exist; it will be stuck on an infinite loop.

```
<img src="image_that_does_not_exist.png" onerror="this.src = 'img/placeholder.png'">
```